# Problem with updating the form from the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone know why the form is updated several times at a time? 
I have the code as below and it works very well, but for a long time. Unnecessarily the form is updated as many times as I have data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CKiQ.png)

```
    function myFunction678() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      var FORM_ID = "XXX";
      var ITEM_ID = 'XXX';
      var options = [];


       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

       var row = data[i];


      if(row[3] == "Text"){
        options.push(row[6]);


      var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);

        form.getItemById(ITEM_ID).asListItem().setChoiceValues(options);

}
}
}
```

Comment: How is your code triggered? Also, looks like your code snippet is incomplete.

Comment: It's trigger from form update. What you think is missing? Only Logger.log is unnecessary.

Comment: Diego is saying your code is incomplete. For example, your `for` loop, `if` statement and your function having no closing braces `}`. Are they intentionally left open like that?

Comment: My code is part of a larger code. This is just an oversight As I said, the code works but the data for the form is updated several times and this is problem. I corrected according to your comments